# Why doesn't LifestyleSingleton() make my object a singleton?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have a "theme repository" to store theme objects

**ITheme**

```
Public Interface ITheme
    Property Name As String
    Property Url As String
End Interface
```

**IThemeRepository**

```
Public Interface IThemeRepository
    Property Themes As IList(Of ITheme)
    Sub Add(theme As ITheme)
End Interface
```

During my application setup I want to add some themes to the repository and then I want anything to be able to access the repository as a sort of in-memory database. This means that the repository needs to have a singleton lifestyle. Even with the following code, a new instance of ThemeRepository is always instantiated:

**RepositoriesInstaller**

```
Public Class RepositoriesInstaller
    Implements IWindsorInstaller

    Public Sub Install(container As Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer,
        store As Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore) _
            Implements IWindsorInstaller.Install
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assemblies.Infrastructure) _
                           .BasedOn(Of IThemeRepository) _
                           .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces _
                           .LifestyleSingleton)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**ThemeRepository**

```
Public Class ThemeRepository
    Implements IThemeRepository

    Public Sub New()
        Themes = New List(Of ITheme)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(theme As ITheme) Implements IThemeRepository.Add
        Themes.Add(theme)
    End Sub

    Public Property Themes As IList(Of ITheme) Implements IThemeRepository.Themes
End Class
```

A `ThemeRepository` service is always found successfully, but it's not a singleton. A new instance of `ThemeRepository` is always resolved. I.e. `New()` is always called on `ThemeRepository`. What's going on?

(*C# or VB.NET code are acceptable in answers*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this strange behaviour was, of course, a silly mistake on my part.

Through a poor coding mistake I was registering my dependencies on every Http request. This meant that everything would work as expected on the first request but then fail after that.

Don't initialise and set up your Castle Windsor container more than once.